# Recycler View Item Spacing In Density Pixels

Tags: android

I noticed an issue with my item decoration for a recycler view which creates a space between each item.

I noticed smaller devices (low res) that the space is larger than on bigger devices (higher res)

This is my code

```
public class SpaceBetweenListItems extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int mSpacing;

    public SpaceBetweenListItems(int spacing){
        this.mSpacing = DisplayMetricsUtils.convertPixelsToDp(spacing);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int currentPosition = parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
        int lastPosition = state.getItemCount()-1;
        outRect.bottom = mSpacing;
        if(currentPosition == lastPosition){
            outRect.bottom = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So i am basically converting the pixels to dp. The logic above is simply applies bottom spacing to all items except the last.

This is the code which converts the pixels to dp

```
 public static int convertPixelsToDp(float px){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.densityDpi / 160.F));
    }
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert dp to pixels, not otherwise.

```
int spacing; // should be in dp
```

Only in this case you will get same physical size of spacing for different screens (screens with different densities).